# Integrating a pdf of a normal distribution is equal to the mean

Tags: probability, integration

This is a very simple question I believe. It's not homework; it's part of a module I'm studying that I want to understand better.

If you have a random variable $X$ that has a normal distribution. Is $E(X)$ equal to integrating the normal distribution equal to the mean of $X$?

Thanks for the answers, I also found it here:
http://www.statlect.com/ucdnrm1.htm

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you get this type of thought from.  $E(X)$ IS the mean of the distribution you want to find.  The definition of $E(X)$ is...

$$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)\,dx$$

where $f(x)$ is any probability distribution with continuous variable.

Comment: yup, that makes sense. Thank you ! I'm sorry I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

$E(X)$ is by definition the mean of $X$. If your random variable is absolutely continuous (i.e. it has probability density $f$), then $$E(X):=\int_{\Bbb R}xf(x)dx.$$